# Resize image in jumbotron to display in completely without scrolling

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a website which has a jumbotron on the home page, I want to resize the height of the image in the jumbotron but display it completely without cutting of any of the picture. I don't want it to scroll to display it either.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block style %}
.img{
    height: 750px;
}

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid img" style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; background-image: url('static/Background.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-3" style="font-weight: 500">S</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is the about me area </p>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this. The required css is as follows

```
.jumbotron{
  background-image: url('static/Background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  padding-bottom:540px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;

}
```

This is the jumbotron

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%;">
    <h1 class="display-3" style="font-weight: 500;">S</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is the about me area </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the scroll, you need to set a vertical height of around 90(Play with this value, in this case for the snippet I used 85), so it fills most of the screen, and it's still responsive. Check code snippet.

I hppe that's what you wanted.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/earth-water-drop-reflection-under-260nw-621430085.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 85vh;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid img">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-3" style="font-weight: 500">John Doe</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is the about me area </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Use background-size: 100% 100%; to stretch the image as shown below, you just need an appropriated ratio image

Comment: I tried this but it is still not showing the full image, I want to compress the height of the image to display it fully in one glance.

Comment: I just edited the snippet, maybe that's what you wanted?

Comment: I'm getting the perfect size on my screen but I still can't see the full image. Am I doing something wrong? The image is still getting cut.

Comment: Maybe if you post the image with your results, we can help more